Changing host permissions on Google Calendar API
When I create a calendar event and add a Google Meet link to the calendar invitation using the Google Calendar API, each attendee has to wait for the admin to let them into the meeting. What properties should I use in my API request (using Node.js) to ensure that every invited attendee can enter the meeting without waiting for admission?
-> This code part should be updated I guess
const res = await calendar.events.insert({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  calendarId: "primary",
  resource: event,
  sendNotifications: true,
  conferenceDataVersion: 1
});

As a@gmail.com, I invited b@gmail.com and c@gmail.com to a calendar event and included a Google Meet link with the invitation. I sent this invitation via the Google Calendar API. Both b@gmail.com and c@gmail.com received the invitation properly. However, when they tried to join the Google Meet through the link, they needed a@gmail.com to let them into the meeting.

okay. So I realized that for meetings created by the Calendar API, the "Host must join before anyone else" option is off by default, which is what I wanted.
However, in Google Calendar (both the API and the app itself), if you create a calendar event and invite attendees, the "Host must join before anyone else" rule applies until very close to the meeting start time (about 5 minutes before). When the meeting time arrives, invited attendees don't have to wait for the host's approval.
